# How to extract XML from zeep response

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, zeep

Suppose I use python zeep to execute a query against a server like this:

```
from zeep import Client

wsdl_url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"

client = Client(wsdl_url)
result = client.service.ListOfContinentsByCode()
```

I would like to see the raw XML that comes back from this method, ie extract it somehow from result. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are looking for is the history plugin.

```py
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from zeep import Client
from lxml import etree

wsdl_url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"

history = HistoryPlugin()
client = Client(wsdl_url, plugins=[history])
client.service.CurrencyName('GBP')
your_pretty_xml = etree.tostring(history.last_received["envelope"], encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: if you get a zeep exception because the response does not validate, start the client with a `settings=Settings(strict=False)`

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to debug the XML in a `zeep` request or response you can use standard Python logging. [From the documentation](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html#debugging):

> To see the SOAP XML messages which are sent to the remote server and the response received you can set the Python logger level to DEBUG for the `zeep.transports` module.

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    ...
    'loggers': {
        'zeep.transports': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Here (requests [takes care](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) of the gzip)

```
import requests
r = equests.get('http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: Nope. This just gets the WSDL document. I want to get the XML response from a SOAP method that is described by the WSDL document. They are totally different things.

Comment: @Marc The url in your post points to the xsd which is a valid xml itself. So I thought you are interested in wsdl doc. Now I understand that you are interested in the xml data that zeep got from the wire and created the result for your call. Is that true?

Comment: @Marc Assuming you want to "see" the xml you can do the following (based on the fact the zeep is using requests as a Transport - https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/4df383021e31372c111bc26cbf2e4535deaee04e/src/zeep/transports.py) , You can set the log level of requests to verbose so requests will print out the data he senst and get back.

Comment: @Marc If the above will not work. You will have to use requests hook.https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks - it will make requests call your code and from here you will be able to see the data.